# Recursively get all possible permutations from an array

Tags: c#, loops, recursion

I have a char array of numbers:

```
static char[] numbers = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

And i need to make a function that combines them in all posible combinations up to 3 digit numbers. Like so:

```
0
1
2
3
00
01
02
03
10
11
12
13
20
21
22
23
30
31
32
33
000
001
002
003
010
011
```

Like that but with all the posible combinatios.
So far i've used a *for* loop with *if* inside but i found that would be better to use recursive functions for that
What is the best and fastest way to do it?

Comment: Short and readable or fast? You can use this fast implementation, it's also worth reading: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G

Comment: fastest as for computer time elapsed for the task, but also the best way of coding it.

Comment: Unless, you want parallel programming, best bet is to do it the way you would naturally do it -- a function starting from character 0 to 9, obtains up to 3 combinations starting from 0 to 9, for all characters. But you will really have to benchmark to find out the real answer for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is the code I came up with.

```
    static char[] numbers = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    static bool continuar = true;

    private static void Start(int maxLength)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxLength; i++)
            Permutations(i, 0, "");
    }

    private static void Permutations(int keyLength, int position, string baseString)
    {
        bool print = true;
        if (continuar)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers .Length; i++)
            {
                string temp = baseString + numbers [i];
                if (position <= keyLength - 1)
                {
                    Permutations(keyLength, position + 1, temp);
                    print = false;
                }
                if (continuar && print)
                    Console.WriteLine(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```